# How to read all string in Jquery including space

Tags: php, jquery

How to read all string including spaces..

in the code below the (value1="+holder[i]['item_desc']+") which is item_desc reads only the first word of the string .. Example the value1 contains "Try is Try" the result will only "Try" .. how can i read the whole string including spaces? so that the output will be "Try is Try" ?

here is my code..

```
 "<td  style='text-align:center'><a onclick='apply(this)'; value1="+holder[i]['item_desc']+" ; value2="+holder[i]['item_quan']+" >Edit Item</a></td>"+

 function app(x){
        var a = $('#item_name').val().length();
        var b = $('#item_desc').val().length();
        var c = $('#item_quan').val().length();
        var d = $('#prov').val().length();
        var e = $('#item_date_post').val().length();

        if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0 && d == 0 && e == 0)
        {
            error();
        }else{
            var y = x.getAttribute('value');
        apply(y);

        }
    }

    function apply(a){

//alert($('#tbl_rptop :input').serialize());
    var holder = new Array();
    var myLink1 = a.getAttribute('value1');
    var myLink2 = a.getAttribute('value2'); 
    $('#item_desc').val(myLink1);
    $('#item_quan').val(myLink2);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }   

    $('#apply').click(function(e) {
        var a = $('#item_name').val();
        var b = $('#item_desc').val();
        var c = $('#item_quan').val();
        var d = $('#prov').val();
        var e =  $('#item_date_post').val();
        if(a == '' ||  c == ''  || d == '' || e == '')
        {
            error();

        }
```

Comment: use this `value1='"+holder[i]['item_desc']+"'` and `value2='"+holder[i]['item_quan']+"'`

Comment: @guradio thank you sir.. its work.. you save my day. =) thanks a lot

Comment: Np chong il put it answer ok?

Comment: @guradio ok sir =)

Comment: close the OP by accepting the answer :)

Comment: @guradio how to do that?

Comment: just tick the check mark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `value1='"+holder[i]['item_desc']+"'`
2. `value2='"+holder[i]['item_quan']+"'`

Need to add `''` to count the spaces.